# How do excel cells have to be formatted to be read as cell_type [:datetime] by Roo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, datetime, roo-gem

I am trying to read DateTime objects from an Excel spreadsheet using the Roo gem.  I am able to successfully read cells that are formatted as Dates with the type *3/14/15 (with the asterisk denoting that the format is based on my regional date and time settings).  When I check the `cell_type` of those cells as they are imported, the type is `[:numeric_or_formula, "mm-dd-yy"]`.  I would expect these to have a type of `[:datetime]`, but I am still able to get a value in mm-dd-yy format from `cell.formatted_value`.

When I try to read cells that are formatted as dates with type 3/14/15 (that is, the format is not based on regional date and time settings) or 3/14/15 13:30 I get that the `cell_type` is `[:numeric_or_formula, "m/d/yy;@"]`.  When I call `cell.formatted_value` I get `"0/d/yy;@"`.

Is there any way to format my excel cells such that they will be read by Roo as being of type `:datetime`? And if not, why is the type of cell in that Roo creates dependent on the regional date and time settings?

For reference, here's the code I have now for reading cells in from the spreadsheet:

```
xlsx = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(self.file)

raw_key_list = xlsx.sheet('index_upload').row(4)
key_list = raw_key_list[4..raw_key_list.length].compact

xlsx.sheet('index_upload').each_row_streaming(offset: 6, pad_cells: true) do |row|

  key_list.each_with_index do |key, idx|

    next unless row[idx + 4].try(:cell_value)

    if row[idx + 4].cell_type == [:numeric_or_formula, "mm-dd-yy"]
      context_lookup.context_value_date = row[idx + 4].formatted_value
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think `cell_type`s in Excel are limited to `l` for label (i.e. text), `n` for numeric (or formula), or `b` for blank cells. Dates are indeed just numbers formatted in a particular way as far as Excel is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I can better determine the type of a cell by checking `class` rather than `cell_type`. Also for the value I set, I found it worked just as well to use the `value` of the cell rather than `formatted_value` - that returns the the DateTime object itself rather than a formatted string of the DateTime.

Here's what the code looks like now:

```
xlsx = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(self.file)

raw_key_list = xlsx.sheet('index_upload').row(4)
key_list = raw_key_list[4..raw_key_list.length].compact

xlsx.sheet('index_upload').each_row_streaming(offset: 6, pad_cells: true) do |row|
key_list.each_with_index do |key, idx|

      next unless row[idx + 4].try(:cell_value)

      if row[idx + 4].class == Roo::Excelx::Cell::DateTime
        context_lookup.context_value_date = row[idx + 4].value
      end
end
```